# how do i found pivote column as date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My table contain six column such as ID,QC_ID,Employee_ID,Created_Date,Created_By 
    my  source table looks like

```
ID|QC_ID|Employee_ID|Status|Created_Date|Created_By
__|_____|___________|______|____________|___________
 1| 1   |   1001    |  P   | 30-08-2019 |  101
 2| 1   |   1002    |  A   | 30-09-2019 |  101
 3| 1   |   1003    |  P   | 30-10 -2019|  101
 4| 1   |   1001    |  A   | 30-10-2019 |  101 
 5| 1   |   1002    |  P   | 30-08-2019 |  101
 6| 1   |   1002    |  A   | 30-10-2019 |  101
 7| 1   |   1003    |  A   | 30-08-2019 |  101
 8| 1   |   1003    |  A   | 30-09-2019 |  101
 9| 1   |   1001    |  A   | 30-09-2019 |  101


and my pivote table should be look like:

ID|QC_ID|Employee_ID|30-08-2019|30-09-2019|30-10-2019
__|_____|___________|__________|__________|___________
 1| 1   |   1001    |   P      |   A      |  A
 2| 1   |   1002    |   P      |   A      |  A
 3| 1   |   1003    |   A      |   A      |  P
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a DYNAMIC PIVOT

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select ID  = min(ID) over (partition by Employee_ID)
              ,QC_ID
              ,Employee_ID
              ,Status
              ,Created_Date = convert(date,Created_Date)
          From YourTable
       ) A
 Pivot (max([Status]) For [Created_Date] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(convert(date,Created_Date)) 
                                                          From YourTable A  
                                                          Order By 1 
                                                          For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  QC_ID   Employee_ID 2019-08-30  2019-09-30  2019-10-30
1   1       1001        P           A           A
2   1       1002        P           A           A
3   1       1003        A           A           P
```

Comment: in Created_date  column all values are showing 'NULL'

Comment: Oct  1 2019 12:38PM Sep 30 2019  9:13PM      Sep 30 2019  9:14PM
 NULL                                NULL                            NULL

Comment: @NitsPatel So Created_Date is a DATETIME?  See updated answer.  I just addeed Created_Date = convert(date,Created_Date)

Comment: Amazing but one more thing i want Created_Date as 30-sep-2019 excluding time

Comment: @dear john currently its showing 30-sep-2019 19:13 PM i want only 30-sep-2019

Comment: @NitsPatel If you look at my updated answer you will see that   >>>   Created_Date = convert(date,Created_Date)   <<<<

Comment: @NitsPatel Just curious.  Is your Created_Date a string or datetime ?

Comment: created_date is datetime datatype

Comment: i replce Created date as  Created_Date = convert(date,Created_Date) but still its showing time why?

Comment: @NitsPatel   see update.  I changed  ...  Select Distinct ','+QuoteName(convert(date,Created_Date))  ...

Comment: while applying QuoteName(convert(date,Created_Date)) i got 2019-09-30 but i want like 30-sep-2019

Comment: @dear john in my table total 15 rows but while applying this query its only showing 5 rows ???

Comment: why its not applicable for all rows ??

Comment: @NitsPatel If you want all rows, remove >>>  = min(ID) over (partition by Employee_ID)  <<<

Comment: Perfect now its showing all rows still in form of 2019-10-01 should i add as 1-oct-219

Comment: @NitsPatel rather than convert(date,date_created) you could have format(date_created,'dd-MMM-yyyy') ... be sure to replace both.  HOWEVER, you will now have an column sequence issue.  This was not part of the original question

Comment: Perfect @johan now i got as i needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional aggregation*.

This solution requires that you know in advance all possible date values (if you don't, then you need to use dynamic SQL, which is a more sophisticated technique).

```
SELECT
    id,
    qc_id,
    employee_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN created_date = CAST('2019-08-30' AS DATE) THEN Status END) AS [30-08-2019],
    MAX(CASE WHEN created_date = CAST('2019-09-30' AS DATE) THEN Status END) AS [30-09-2019],
    MAX(CASE WHEN created_date = CAST('2019-10-30' AS DATE) THEN Status END) AS [30-10-2019]
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 
    id,
    qc_id,
    employee_id
```

Comment: i am getting this error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Created_Date column value will be Dynamic

Comment: @NitsPatel: I edited my answer to fix the conversion error.